# What would make a jQuery event delegation not work?

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup inside the body tag, and before my script loads:

```
<ul class="wizard-menu">
 <li class="top">
  <div class="top-category custom-select">Select Category</div>
  <ul class="menu-main" style="display: none;">
   <li id="top-2" class="menu-expense"><a href="#" id="category-2" class="wizard-category-name">Menu Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

On page load the following works and prints to the console:

```
$(function() {  
 $(".wizard-category-name").click(function() {
  console.log("Non-Delegated");
 });
});
```

But this does not:

```
$(function() {  
 $("body").on("click", ".wizard-category-name", function() {
  console.log("Delegated");
 });
});
```

I'm using delegates like this throughout my code, but only this one is breaking which makes me think it's something dumb... any ideas?

Comment: Most likely something above that element also has a click event, but is either returning false or stopping propagation. The only way around it is to change the delegate target to inside the element that stops the propagation, change the handler that is stopping the propagation, or don't use delegation for that event.

Comment: where is the jsbin ?>

Comment: Bingo, Kevin you nailed it (stopPropagation).  If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark as correct.

Comment: I'm hoping that you are categorizing magical wizards with this form and not building a boring wizard interface :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a delegated event isn't being triggered, more than likely another event is stopping the propagation that delegated events rely on. Look for `event.stopPropagation` and/or a `return false` in elements that are ancestors of the element that you are trying to track an event on.